# Overloading addition for a class representing a set of functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm creating a class `my_class` whose only instance variable is `member`, a numpy array with dimensions `(N, 2)` for any arbitrary `N`. This class is supposed to represent a vector space of real functions. If `A.member` looks like

`[[a_1, x_1], [a_2, x_2], ..., [a_N, x_N]]`

then `A` represents the function

`f(x) = a_1 * k(x, x_1) + a_2* k(x, x_2) + ... + a_n * k(x, x_N)`

where `k(x, y)` is a pre-chosen function. I want to overload addition for this class in the common-sense way so that if `A.member` contains `[a, x_0]` and `B.member` contains `[b, x_0]`, then `(A + B).member` contains  `[a + b, x_0]`. If `A.member` contains `[a, x_0]` and `B.member` contains no pair in which `x_0` is the second index, `(A + B).member` should contain `[a, x_0]`. So far, I've implemented addition like this:

```py
def __add__(self, other): 
    a = np.intersect1d(self.member[:,1], other.member[:,1], True, True)
    b = np.intersect1d(self.member[:,1], np.setdiff1d(self.member[:,1], a[0]),True, True)
    c = np.intersect1d(other.member[:,1], np.setdiff1d(other.member[:,1], a[0]),True, True)
    common = np.concatenate(((self.member[a[1],:][:,0] + other.member[a[2],:][:,0]).reshape(-1, 1), a[0].reshape(-1, 1)), 1)
    return my_class(np.concatenate((common, self.member[b[1],:], other.member[c[1],:]), 0))
```

I think this is overly cumbersome and not very well written. Also currently, my code does not remove entries of the form `[0, x_0]` which would be nice. Is there a better way to implement this? If possible, I would like to stick to numpy arrays and not resort to dictionaries.

Comment: As an aside I've noticed that `np.intersect1d` will sometimes produce indices which are out of bounds, is there any way to deal with this?

Comment: If there are only a fixed number of possible ```x_0,..., x_M``` and each instance has some of them, I think you could implement this functionality quite nice with sparse vectors (e.g. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032946/how-to-efficiently-create-a-sparse-vector-in-python). For sparse vectors (or matrices) addition operators are available.

Comment: I don't know that you'd be resorting to dictionaries - it seems that they're better suited to this problem.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a minimum example?

Comment: Would you consider pandas as a dependency? It looks like a problem that the join function could handle.

Comment: It might be helpful to see your problem as addition of polynomials. k(x, x_M) is formally identical to x^x_M as far as addition is concerned. If x_M has a non-fixed range I'd use a dictionary to represend your function and not a ndarray.